# jQuery custom code not working in shopify

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify

I am trying to create anchor tag on `<span>` element. Here is my code:

```js
$(function() {
  $("span.bold_option_value_title:contains('I Booked An Appointment')").click(function() {
    window.open('https://regentrepair.com/pages/book-your-repair', '_blank');
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="bold_option_value ">
  <label>
    <span class="bold_option_value_element">
      <input type="checkbox" class="cbm_1690320_664816" value="I Booked An Appointment " data-option_value_key="0">
    </span>
    <span class="bold_option_value_title">I Booked An Appointment </span>
  </label>
</span>
```

I am putting the code in theme.liquid file before the body closing tag but it is not working.

I tried this code in console without $(function()) this code is working but if i put it in theme.liquid it is not working. I also tried "Onload" but still no success.

Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: The code shown in your question works (although the new window is blocked from being opened by the sandbox settings in the SO snippet iframe - you can see this happening in the console). If it's not working for you I would suggest that you need to either use a delegated event handler and check the console for errors. Also note that it makes very little sense to attach the event to the `span` by the content. Attach the event to the change event of the checkbox, and interrogate the element to determine if it was actually checked before opening the new window

Comment: Thank you for your kind help. I can not set it to checkbox because checkbox is being controlled by another shopify app called Product Option by bold and it is adding a set amount to cart so this is why I am trying to set it on `span`.